# Can I customize how a property is serialized to xml within a partial class?

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, xml-serialization

I have a set of entities that are generated by the [EF Reverse POCO Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2). Using the Audit Log feature of [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log) I can serialize changes to my entities to Xml except when the entity has a property of type `DbGeography`. In Reverse POCO, I've set the option `DisableGeographyTypes=true` so this property no longer gets generated and I've added a partial (non-generated) class and put the property in there instead.

Is there an attribute I can add to this property that will allow me to customize how it gets serialized to XML? Something like `[SomeXmlAttribute(MyCustomSerializer)]` where MyCustomSerializer is a class that will allow me to convert the data type to and from Xml?

Comment: There are plenty attributes to manage serialization. Depends on what you want *exactly* if one of them applies.

Comment: @GertArnold I want to serialize the `DbGeography` property to XML. What other info do you need?